# How to alter table by changing the entity in JPA with auto-ddl=update

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I changed the entity `UserInfoEntity`, variable name from 'moblie' to 'mobile', and then I restarted my server. when I looked at the table i found that the table hasn't removed the column 'moblie'. Here is my change in entity;

From this;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pe_userinfo")
public class UserInfoEntity {
    private String moblie;
}
```

to this;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pe_userinfo")
public class UserInfoEntity {
    private String mobile;
}
```

Comment: What is "auto-dll" ? JPA has no such property. It has some properties `javax.persistence.schema-generation.*`. In general a JPA provider is not the most appropriate tool to handle schema upgrading ... better to use Liquibase/Flyway for that

Comment: Makes no sense to use Hibernate specific things when there are JPA standard equivalents

Comment: @BillyFrost `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` it is well within JPA, no problem to access them at all.

Comment: Nope. It is not a JPA standard property. It is a HIBERNATE specific property. The clue is in the name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `auto-ddl=create-drop` to drop the faulty schema in its entirety & recreate it with fixed column value, you cannot have update schema in such manner.

Also check [Hibernate: hbm2ddl.auto=update in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221379/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-update-in-production), as it says, it is better to handle such cases manually by yourself rather than using Hibernate to handle such modifications on an existing schema.

**Extra Idea**

If you wish to save your data;

- You can create a separate table to hold your data `pe_userinfo_temp`
- deploy your product, auto-ddl will create `pe_userinfo_temp`
- use jpa logic to copy data from `pe_userinfo` -> `pe_userinfo-temp`
- drop the table `pe_userinfo` manually from datasource
- fix your column in `pe_userinfo`, auto-ddl will create it but will be empty
- use similar jpa logic to copy data from `pe_userinfo_temp` -> new `pe_userinfo`
- then finally drop the `pe_userinfo_temp` from your source code & drop from datasource

Comment: it works out. But it will drop the table and delete all records which I expect to be saved

Comment: @陈杨华 I know, there is no other way with Hibernate sadly, you can access the datasource & edit the column yourself manually.

Comment: I want to find a way to solve this problem like making migrations in Python through Django

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you're using hibernate (may be even inside spring-data-jpa) and indeed it doesn't rename the tables but creates new ones. Moreover you shouldn't use (hibernate) auto update in any more or less serious environments.

Use [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) or [liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) instead.