# How do I modify only part of an entity in spring data jpa?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

How do I modify only part of an entity in Spring Data JPA?

Here is my code.

```
public void modifyDrawing(Long no, String name, Double lat, Double lon, String physicalName, String desc) {
   Drawing drawing = drawingRepository.findById(no)
       .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);

   drawing.setName(name);
   drawing.setLat(lat);
   drawing.setLon(lon);
   drawing.setPhysicalName(physicalName);
   drawing.setDesc(desc);
   drawingRepository.save(drawing);
}
```

At this time, if `lat` and `lon` are null, I want to keep the values without changing them. I am wondering how to update the entity value using only non-null parameter values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA: update only specific fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818334/jpa-update-only-specific-fields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add an `if` check to make sure the latitude/longitude are not `null` before calling their setters.

```java
public void modifyDrawing(Long no, String name, Double lat, Double lon, String physicalName, String desc) {
    Drawing drawing = drawingRepository.findById(no)
        .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);

    drawing.setName(name);
    if (lat != null) {
        drawing.setLat(lat);
    }
    if (lon != null) {
        drawing.setLon(lon);
    }
    drawing.setPhysicalName(physicalName);
    drawing.setDesc(desc);
    drawingRepository.save(drawing);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was wondering if there is an elegant way other than if(... != null).

Comment: There isn't a more elegant way AFAIK.  If you call the setter then that column will appear in the `SET` clause of the underlying update query.