# JPA updates a column/attribute that is not modified

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, default-value

We have a class `User`, which has a field `isMigrated` which is `0` by default. Now in the service layer, we are trying to update the user's `status` (another attribute). So these are the steps

1. We fetch the user by his ID (Primary key).
2. We set the new status.
3. We call the `save` method in the respective repository for that particular user.

Now the problem is that the column that corresponds to `isMigrated`, which is currently having a value of `1` is also getting updated to `0`. We have clearly not updated that attribute and so we came to a conclusion that it is the default value that is going to the DB during updation, but how is that possible?

We tried to check some other information about [JPA: update only specific fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818334/jpa-update-only-specific-fields) but wasn't helpful in this case. We had to go with native query to fix this problem.

**Entity class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_TABLE")
public class User implements Serializable {

    //  other attributes

    @Column(name = "USER_STATUS")
    private int status;

    //  [1 = migrated, 0 = new (default)]
    @Column(name = "IS_MIGRATED")
    private int isMigrated = 0;

    //  getters and setters
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository
        extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {
}
```

**Updates regarding how the user is being fetched**

The user is fetched by his ID from the request, we'll run a native query by joining two other tables by fetching only the required fields. So in the process of fetch, we are not using the `isMigrated` column, plus that attribute (call hierarchy) is set only when a user is created and this is a different API.

Once we fetch the user, it's reference is set to an attribute of another bean `RequestInfo` with a Request scope (`@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)`), which will be used all along the API. Now in the service layer we use the `RequestInfo` to get the user, then we set the new status and call the `save` method.

```
@Query(value = "select um.USER_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,USER_STATUS,um.MOB,EMAIL_ID,ENTITY_TYPE,PROFILE_ID,PARENT_ID,SOFT_DELETE, NATIONALITY_ID,DOB,GENDER,FATHER_NAME,QUALIFICATION,LANGUAGE_ID,DESIGNATION,CONTRACT_START_DATE, "
        + "CONTRACT_END_DATE, REGISTERED_DATE,ACTIVATED_DATE,CREATED_BY,CONTACT_EMAIL_ID,CONTACT_MSISDN,ERP_CODE, "
        + "LAST_FINANCIAL_TXN_DATE,MM_APP_VERSION,MM_APP_LAST_UPDATE_DATE,OFFICIAL_EMAIL_ID,SRC_OF_FUND,POW, JOB_NAME,JOB_STARTED,MONTHLY_INCOME, "
        + "MARITAL_STATUS,SALUTE,HIER_ID,LABEL_ID,PROFILE_PICTURE_ID,DOC_NAME,lm.ID , lm.ALERT_DATE , lm.BLOCKED_DATE , lm.IS_FORCE_PIN , lm.IS_FORCE_PASSWORD , lm.LAST_LOGIN_TIME , lm.LAST_NOTIFIED_DATE ,lm.PASSWORD , lm.PIN ,  "
        + "lm.WRONG_PIN_ATTEMPT , lm.PIN_EXPIRY_DATE , lm.WRONG_PWD_ATTEMPT , lm.PWD_EXPIRY_DATE , lm.USER_NAME, am.ID aid, am.ADDRESS_1, am.ADDRESS_2, am.ADDRESS_TYPE, am.CITY , am.PIN_CODE , am.POST_BOX , am.STATE , am.STREET_NAME,ui.ID_TYPE, ui.ID_NO,um.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_TYPE "
        + " FROM USER_TABLE um inner join USER_LOGIN_TABLE lm ON um.USER_ID=lm.USER_ID and um.USER_ID=?1 "
        + " left outer join USER_ADDRESS_TABLE am ON um.USER_ID=am.USER_ID left outer join USER_IDENTI_CATION_DETAILS ui ON um.USER_ID = ui.USER_ID", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> getUserByUserId(String userId);
```

**Updates regarding the columns that are not fetched while getting a user - Asked by Ratul Sharker**

There are a few columns that we are not fetching, like `deviceId`, `deviceIp`, etc. These are `String` types, so even though we are not providing a default value to these fields `null` will be assigned as the default value. So my doubt is why the default value is inserted into `isMigrated` and why the same is not inserted to the other two fields because these three are not fetched in the above query right?

Comment: You need to show the code that is fetching it and  doing the update.

Comment: And how did you map `status`?

Comment: Calling `CrudRepository.save`  generates an sql statement updating all entity fields regardless is they are updated or not. Most probably, you are trying to update an transient object with id, that causes merge with persisted one

Comment: Good luck finding an answer without showing the actual code

Comment: @DavideD'Alto, I've added the native query that I mentioned

Answer (score 1):

The way JPA works is following

- You fetch the object from the database.
- You fetch the complete object, or having lazily loaded jpa provider's proxy object attached to the fetched object.
- Do whatever modification you want.
- You call the `save` method, it rans some internal dirty checking.
- Based on the dirty checking, it generates the `UPDATE` sql statement.

In your case, you didn't fetch the `isMigrated` field during reading the entity and your entities default value set's it to `0`.

What are the options

1. If you don't want to update the `isMigrated` field from the jpa layer consider define the column annotation as `@Column( name= "IS_MIGRATED", updatable = false)`
2. Fetch the `isMigrated` field, carry forward until you save the entity.
3. (Worst idea ever) Instead of using `save` method write tedious JPQL like following inside the repository interface

```java
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE User user SET user.name = :name /*other set statements*/ WHERE user.id = :userId")
public void updateUser(@Param("name") String name, /*other properties*/, @Param("userId") int userId);
```

**Response to the update in the question**

The fields you are mentioning, `deviceId`, `deviceIP` these sort of fields are meant to be updated from the `HTTPServlerRequest`. I need to see your complete code. I guess before saving the users these properties are set from the `HTTPServletRequest` parameter. There are numerous way to setting these fields

- Using `@PrePersist`, `@PreUpdate` inside the entity.
- Setting these values from `HTTPServletRequest` inside service layer or controller layer.

This is why these values are setting to proper values, which is different from `isMigrated` field.

Comment: But @Ratul Sharker, I'm also not fetching some other columns as well for which we haven't specified a default value, but they still will be assigned one right? Those columns are not having this issue.

Comment: please spceify an example in your question, because, your comment requires more information to answer.

Comment: updated the answer according to your update.