# Java: How to ignore fields which has null and pass only with modified property

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I wrote an update method which accepts fields that are modified.

```
 public ResponseEntity<String> updateProduct(@RequestBody final Product product)
 {
  returnValue = productService.updateProduct(product);
 }
```

Product is a bean class holds 50 property list. From UI if i modify 5 fields it holds those modified fields and other properties as null. How to perform filter here? I want to pass only updated value

```
 returnValue = productService.updateProduct(product);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its pretty hard to say without seeing any code from the `Product` class nor the `ProductService.updateProduct` method. However you may be able to to use the `BeanUtilsBean` class provided in the Apache Commons library.

```
public static void nullAwareBeanCopy(Object dest, Object source) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    new BeanUtilsBean() {
        @Override
        public void copyProperty(Object dest, String name, Object value)
                throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
            if(value != null) {
                super.copyProperty(dest, name, value);
            }
        }
    }.copyProperties(dest, source);
}
```

This is one I wrote but since your using spring you may want to use the spring bean utils class located at `org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils`. Doing a quick search for that code I came across [this answer from alfredx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737626/how-to-ignore-null-values-using-springframework-beanutils-copyproperties-solve#answer-19739041) which has this code

```
public static String[] getNullPropertyNames (Object source) {
    final BeanWrapper src = new BeanWrapperImpl(source);
    java.beans.PropertyDescriptor[] pds = src.getPropertyDescriptors();

    Set<String> emptyNames = new HashSet<String>();
    for(java.beans.PropertyDescriptor pd : pds) {
        Object srcValue = src.getPropertyValue(pd.getName());
        if (srcValue == null) emptyNames.add(pd.getName());
    }
    String[] result = new String[emptyNames.size()];
    return emptyNames.toArray(result);
}

// then use Spring BeanUtils to copy and ignore null
public static void myCopyProperties(Object, src, Object target) {
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(src, target, getNullPropertyNames(src))
}
```

You can then use it like:

```
public void updateProduct(Product updatedProduct) {
    Product existingProduct = /*find existing product*/;
    nullAwareBeanCopy(existingProduct, updatedProduct);
    // or 
    myCopyProperties(updatedProduct, existingProduct);
}
```

**Watchout these 2 different methods source/destination parameters are opposite of eachother.**

Comment: Watch out for updates where the actual new value has to be null ;) if you are never sending "clear" values you can use your approach, else you need a way to track which fields have been set by the request.