# How to set fields on an existing object only if the corresponding fields on an input object are not null

Tags: java

How can I set values into an `existing` object only if the `incoming` fields are not null? On form submission, I check to see if incoming fields are not null, before updating the existing object on a database save. I have too many fields and too many snippets for each field. Is there an elegant way to set only the updated fields on the `existing` object?

```
protected void updateFoo(Foo input, Foo existing) {
    if (input.getEducation() != null) {
        existing.setEducation(input.getEducation());
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Spring has something called `BeanUtils.copyProperties` that can be configured to skip null values. This question deals with that situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737626/how-to-ignore-null-values-using-springframework-beanutils-copyproperties

Comment: @Andy intention is to reduce complexity at the updateFoo either using additional libraries or other utilities or any build time annotations. Appreciate if you can provide possible options to resolve, as the number of attributes keeps increasing all the time and it adds to more maintenance

Answer (score 1):

You can combine all fields within a map. When any new values occur, update a sub-map and just transfer the sub-map to the receiver.

https://www.javatpoint.com/java-map

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html

Example:

`your database row`

```
Value: 1  2  3  4  5
```

You create one time a map out of any database row, maybe row 0 and use this map as reference card at your receiver side.

`myMap`

```
Key:   A  B  C  D  E
Value: 1  2  3  4  5
```

Your database changes to:

`your database row`

```
Value: 1  2  7  4  9
```

You create a sub-map.

`mySubMap`

```
Key:   C  E
Value: 7  9
```

You transfer that sub-map to the receiver and update the receiver.

There are some minor logical bugs in this text, but I hope you get the idea.

PS maps work faster than endless if...else, especially in huge databases